# How to connect django with mongodb compass?

Tags: python, django

I installed **djongo** through pip. My django version is 3 although I checked version 2 also to make it work. Python version is 3. I also made change in **settings.py** but whenever I load the command with makemigrations, it gives me following error.

```
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql','oracle','postgresql','sqlite3'
```

I don't know what to do with this now?

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    default: {
           'ENGINE': 'djongo',
           'NAME' : 'django_db'
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

there's this awesome package that allows you to connect Django with MongoDB it's called mongoengine 
http://mongoengine.org/

here's also a link for their documentation

http://docs.mongoengine.org/